# How to throw an Error inside pg pool query in Express JS?

Tags: javascript, express, try-catch, throw

I am facing trouble when I try to throw an Error (to mark if there are no username) inside pool query. What I am expect is the error was catch by `checkUsername` and make it standard json response. But, I always get an error like this:

[image: error details]

Here is my code in controller:

```
const checkUsername = (req, res) => {
  const service = new AuthService()
  try {
    service.chekcUsernameIsExist(req.body.username, res)

    return res.status(200).send('Username is exist')
  } catch (error) {
    const response = {
      status: false,
      message: error.message,
      error_code: 400
    }
    return res.status(400).send(response)
  }
}
```

And here is my code in service:

```
class AuthService {
  chekcUsernameIsExist (username) {
    const query = `select * from admins where username = '${username}';`

    pool.query(query, (err, results, release) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err
      } else if (results.rowCount !== 0) {
        console.log('Username is exist')
      } else {
        console.log('Username is not exist')
        throw new Error('Username is not exist')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I try to add try catch block inside `checkUsernameIsExist` but still got the same problem. At the stupid, I add a variable to which have value 1, 2, or 3 to mark is username exist, not exist, or other error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: But note if you _don't_ pass a callback the query method returns a promise instead, which is much easier to deal with.

Comment: thank you for giving me insight about asynchronous. I will try to apply it.